# How to create independent Realm Objects

Tags: objective-c, realm

I have a realm object that holds an array of objects.

```
RLM_ARRAY_TYPE(ContactObject)
@interface PersonObject : RLMObject
@property RLMArray< ContactObject *>< ContactObject > *contactArray;
@end
```

After I initiate the PersonObject, and add data to contactArray, I am trying to create another temporary person object.

```
PersonObject *tempPersonObj = [[PersonObject alloc]init];
```

and I assign old personObject to this temporary object;

```
   tempPersonObj = oldPErsonObj;
```

Now if I delete the contact array objects in tempPersonOBj, the contact array objects in oldPersonObj gets deleted too.

Why is this happening ? Is there any way to copy data into a temporary object without affecting the database?

Answer (score 1):

When you assign `tempPersonObj = oldPersonObj`, you're not making a copy of the old person object. Instead, you now have two references to the same underlying person object, so changing one will cause the other to change as well. More generally, all `RLM*` types provided by Realm are actually just references to the underlying database and objects.

If you need a temporary object, you should make a new object (as you are doing) and copy the properties individually. For lists, you should copy the `RLMObject`s out of the original object's list property and add them to the new object's list property.

Comment: Even though I copied individual items, the copied object changes when the original one is changed! SOmehow all the realm objects are connected!